# Loading Text File From Resource

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

i've been trying to retrieve some data from a .JSON file. Im currently using Unity with SimpleJson and when I load up the game i get this error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object PlayerInteraction.test () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/PlayerInteraction.cs:93) PlayerInteraction.Start () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/PlayerInteraction.cs:23)

here is the code:

```
void test(){
    string filepath = (Application.dataPath + "/listofgames.txt");
    TextAsset file = Resources.Load(filepath) as TextAsset;
    var node = JSON.Parse(file.text); //line 93
    var pl = node["apps"];
        Debug.Log("TEST: " + pl[0]);
}
```

Comment: My best guess is that `Resources.Load(filepath)` is returning null or it's not convertible to `TextAsset. Have you debugged?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Solved, i've read up on Resources.Load and it only grabs files from the resources folder ( i knew that but still didn't work). ALong with that you're not supposed to use ".txt" or ".JSON" as a suffix, just the file name. But thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

[`Resources.load`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) only works for files in Resources folder. Try to move your file `listofgames.txt` to the Resources folder (create it if you need), then call `Resources.load("listofgames")` (you must omit file extension).

Please note you can also have `TextAsset` fields so you can reference to it in the inspector. This works with `TextAsset`s outside of Resources:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public TextAsset asset;
    void Start() {
        print(asset.text);
    }
}
```